# Matrix writing goes wrong

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I want to write down this matrix in my latex document

[image]

My code for that is

```
\begin{document}
$$ F_x=
\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
  &   &   &   & 3N Columns
\end{bmatrix}
$$
\end{document}
```

This code not produce desired result.  Where should I change to produce desire result?

Comment: Side note: use `\[...\]` and not `$$...$$` for display math!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated. You can do it with nested matrices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ F_x=
\begin{bmatrix}
\, % for symmetry
\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} &
\smash{\underbrace{%
  \begin{matrix}
  0 & \dots & 0 \\
  0 & \dots & 0 \\
  0 & \dots & 0
  \end{matrix}}_{\text{$3N$ columns}}%
}\,
\end{bmatrix}
\vphantom{%
\underbrace{%
  \begin{matrix}
  0 & \dots & 0 \\
  0 & \dots & 0 \\
  0 & \dots & 0
  \end{matrix}}_{\text{$3N$ columns}}%
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\vphantom` is needed to maintain the real size of the object, because we smash the second inner matrix in order TeX doesn't “see” the depth of the underbrace.

You can simplify the input by defining a temporary macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\tempmatrix}{%
  \underbrace{%
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \dots & 0 \\
    0 & \dots & 0
    \end{matrix}}_{\text{$3N$ columns}%
  }%
}
F_x=
\begin{bmatrix}
\, % for symmetry
\begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} &
\smash{\tempmatrix}
\,
\end{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\tempmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Frankly, I'dont see any difference using or not using the vphantom instruction. Are you this is useful, compiling with overleaf.com no difference seeable on the output pdf?

Comment: @pzorba75 Add some text after the display and see.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is as a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `matrix of nodes`:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{E:columns}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
     \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,
                 left delimiter=(,
                 right delimiter=)]{
          1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
          0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
          0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
      };
      \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}]
      (M-3-4.south west)--(M-3-6.south east)
        node[font=\scriptsize,below left]{$3N$ columns};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For that tikz must be install. I am using tex studio.

Comment: @Saswati There is no problem to load tikz on TeXStudio....

Comment: Can we add equation number?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda If you want an equation number then put everything inside an `equation` environment. I'll edit since I didn't put the label in `\scriptsize`.

Answer (score 0):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of the package `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
F_x =
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin=2pt]
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[shorten=1mm]{3-4}{3-6}{3N \text{ columns}} 
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]